# Assigning strings to array elements in Bash, syntax error?

Tags: bash, syntax, scripting

This line from a loop is supposed to add the three strings together

```
for each $drivecount
${drives[$drivecount]}=${info[$count+1]}" "${info[$count+2]}" "${info[$count+3]}
```

Here is the error I am getting:

```
./erasehd.sh: line 17: =/dev/sda: 80.0 GB: No such file or directory
```

It looks like it is including the = as part of the first string?

Answer (score 2):

```
./erasehd.sh: line 17: =/dev/sda: 80.0 GB: No such file or directory
```

No, its ignoring the undeclared variable at the front and trying to execute `=/dev/sda...` as a command. ;-)  .... You want

```
for each $drivecount
drives[$drivecount]=${info[$count+1]}" "${info[$count+2]}" "${info[$count+3]}
```

When setting a variable, you never want a leading '$' on a variable, or put another way, typically you don't want a '$' on the left-hand-side of the '=' assignment.

I'm not familiar with the `for each` construct in bash. Are you sure that is right? I would expect something like

```
for drivecount in 1 2 3 ; do
 ....
```

Finally, the syntax you included is used for referencing an array element, unrelated to assignments.

```
for dc in 1 2 3 ; do
  echo ${drives[$dc]}
done
```

IHTH.